# How to ensure the tasks in the pool should get finish before the program exits?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

I am currently working on a multi threaded document similarity program. Simply put this extract of the program gets an object, passes it to a "hasher" method ,minhashes a value of the object and adds it to a list to be manipulated in order to test similarity .

My issue is that the main thread seems to advance to where I manipulate the list whilst the threads from the pool are still running and minhashing the object values,using println I could see that the program had ran till to the end but the threads were still executing in the run() method after.

How can I ensure that the tasks in the pool should get finished before the program advances?

```
int docCount = 2;
    while (docCount > 0) {
        try {
            Shingle s = q.take();

            if (s instanceof Poisin == false) {
                pool.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("DEBUG : currently in run()" + Thread.currentThread());

                        if (s.getDocumentId() == 1) {
                            list1.add(hasher(s));
                        } else if (s.getDocumentId() == 2) {
                            list2.add(hasher(s));
                        } else {
                            voidList.add(hasher(s));
                        }
                    }
                });// Runnable
            } else {
                docCount--;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("INteruppted exception " + e);
        }
    }

    float k1 = list1.size();
    float k2 = list2.size();
    System.out.println("DEBUG : End of program" + Thread.currentThread());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I ensure that the tasks in the pool have completed before the
>   program advances?

Use to initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, you need to call below methods after submitting tasks to executor. Because, calling `shutdown` will reject any new task afterward.

```
pool.shutdown();
```

Then after

```
pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // specify timeout here
```

On [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) page, it was very well documented with an example (copied) :

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

Above, method will ensure, there are no new task submitted and will wait for atmost `60` seconds to finish all tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Try shutting down the executor service and waiting for all the threads to terminate before trying to process your results.

```
<Submit work to thread pool>
..

executorService.shutdownNow();
executorService.awaitTermination();
..
<Process results from threads>
```